The declaration of `std::as_const` seems over-complicated
If we will look at std::as_const declaration, we will see this:
template< class T >
constexpr std::add_const_t<T>& as_const( T& t ) noexcept;

It returns std::add_const_t<T>& that, according to cppreference.com, looks like this:
template< class T >
using add_const_t    = typename add_const<T>::type;

And add_const looks like this:
template<class T>
struct add_const
{
    typedef const T type;
};

So, it declares struct that contains only typedef for constant version of template type and, when as_const(T& t) returns t, it converts it to const through that typedef.
So, why std::as_const could not just look like this?
template<typename T>
constexpr const T& as_const(T& t) noexcept
{
    return t;
}

I created some test code:
template<typename T>
constexpr const T& my_as_const(T& t) noexcept
{
    return t;
}

struct foo
{
    void m() { std::cout << "Non-constant\n"; }
    void m() const { std::cout << "Const\n"; }
};

void print()
{
    std::cout << "Test\n";
}

int main()
{
    foo z;
    z.m();
    my_as_const(z).m();
    std::as_const(z).m();

    auto&& a = my_as_const(z);
    auto&& b = std::as_const(z);

    std::cout << "Address of z: " << &z << '\n';
    std::cout << "Address of a: " << &a << '\n';
    std::cout << "Address of b: " << &b << '\n';

    void (*fp_print)() { print };
    fp_print();
    my_as_const(fp_print)();
    std::as_const(fp_print)();

    const foo x;
    x.m();
    my_as_const(x).m();
    std::as_const(x).m();

    return 0;
}

It prints:
Non-constant
Const
Const
Address of z: 00AFFEAB
Address of a: 00AFFEAB
Address of b: 00AFFEAB
Test
Test
Test
Const
Const
Const


cppreference only says "Possible implementation". A real implementation might be more complicated, to avoid having the compiler warn  about trying to add const to function  pointers, or to types that are already const.

Some of those traits, such as std::add_lvalue_reference, have to handle more cases where you can't simply implement it as T&. One could argue using the traits whenever that level of genericity is required rather than everyone having to remember which traits have extra cases and which don't.

"my_as_const..." I see what you did there. Coming to the issue, are you looking for cases where my_as_const would give different result than as_const?

what if it is passed an rvalue reference instead ? your function will convert it to an lvalue reference, which is not correct

@AhmedAEK for rvalue references std::as_const function is deleted:
template< class T > void as_const( const T&& ) = delete;
so could do I, question only about lvalue references

Imagine you can also have rvalue references etc. that might not even be convertible to const. as_const can then warn you about those problems as well.

That's not just a possible implementation, that's literally the function signature in the standard. Reusing the trait prevents its behavior from shifting away from std::as_const in case the language evolves, and the traits needs some adjustment (sharing behavior is a common point in favor of reuse in software anyway). Besides, the whole point of as_const was to have the standard provide a common pattern which used add_const anyway.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, yeah, to keep consistency add_const should be defined in terms of add_const_t, and add_const_t should be defined as decltype(add_const(…)). :)
